# How to apply Holo style to TabWidget?

Tags: android, tabwidget

I'm using HoloEverywhere for layout style compatibility with Gingerbread version, however TabWidget layout is still in old Gingerbread version. How can I apply Holo style to TabWidget?

Thanks in advance.